# Transposing a whole set in to a range in one go

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently looping through my nodelist and planting the value in a cell, adding one to a counter variable and repeating till loop is finished...

```
For Each n In myXML.SelectNodes("//a")
    .Cells(X, 2).Value = n.Attributes.getNamedItem("href").Text
    X = X + 1
Next n
```

It's a little slow with a few thousand rows so I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this? Perhaps by getting the list in to an array then transposing the array? Not too sure where to start on it but see last line for an idea :/

Full WORKING code below

```
Sub gogo()

Dim theXMLstring As String
Dim theXMLdocument As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim n As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Long

    theXMLstring = "<table><a href=""no"">hi</a><a href=""yes"">bye</a><a href=""WOAH"">woah</a></table>"
    theXMLdocument.LoadXML (theXMLstring)

    For Each n In theXMLdocument.SelectNodes("//a")
        MsgBox (n.Attributes.getNamedItem("href").Text)
    Next n

End Sub
```

What I really want is something like `MyArr() = theXMLdocument.SelectNodes("//a").Attributes.getNamedItem("href").Text`

Comment: If you want to speed things up writing them to an array might be a good intermediate yes. I'm not sure however if your current code works.

Comment: I appreciate this might be difficult but is there an example fuller case to play around with? I totally get some people will probably know straight out. Can't you get a collection of hrefs somehow and transpose?

Comment: I'll try to write a full working example

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail.

Comment: Would parsing using split not be suitable? Create an array and transpose out.

Comment: Hmm I could split the string up to obtain the href text, without even using  an xml dom document (It's actually a string I get in the first instance anyway) - I wasn't sure if this'd be faster than traversing the domdocument though... some testing needed I guess

Comment: Not overly helpful but found I could also do theXMLdocument.SelectNodes("//a/@href")

Comment: Never seen that one before, looks handy for condensing!

Comment: You end up with a DOM selection and I can't find any method exposed that avoids the need for an iterator. Parsing with split also looked to be a pain meaning something like the answer given seems a good way to go.

Comment: Splitting the text was fairly easy but on my scale didn't really make much of a difference. I actually had a speed increase anyway after I'd restarted Excel (shame on me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not used to XML, but I'm pretty sure that just optimization on worksheet writing will make huge difference (UI vs in-memory):

```
Dim arr()
For Each n In myXML.SelectNodes("//a")
    x=x+1
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 to x)
    arr(x) = n.Attributes.getNamedItem("href").Text
Next n
Cells(1,1).Resize(x).Value=WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
```

EDIT: Although `ReDim` optimization is minor against single Range assignment, I 'm publishing suggested optimization:

```
Dim arr(), nodes, i As Long
Set nodes = myXML.SelectNodes("//a")
ReDim arr(1 To nodes.Length, 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To nodes.Length
    arr(i, 1) = nodes(i - 1).Attributes.getNamedItem("href").Text
Next
Cells(1, 1).Resize(nodes.Length).Value = arr
```

Comment: Great idea, sure I've seen the concept before but forget due to never using it. I'll try it now and see how much time it saves. Thanks!

Comment: I would avoid all the ReDim's which make copies. You know how many items there are (Length), so just ReDim once at the start to the right size.

Comment: I've took both your advice and done just this to speed things up. Accepted as the right answer since there were no others anyway :D